# Laravel Eloquent Nested Group by its Relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Please help me how to add another nested group by based on game category relation. I have 3 tables related using laravel 5.4 eloquent.

**Game Providers Table**

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------------------+
| id | game_name   | game_type_id | game_category_id |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------------+
|  1 | Sample      |      1       |         1        |
|  1 | Sample 0    |      1       |         2        |
|  2 | Sample 1    |      2       |         1        |
|  3 | Sample 2    |      2       |         2        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------------+
```

**Game Types**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Chess       |
|  2 | Poker       |
+----+-------------+
```

**Game Categories**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Recommended |
|  2 | Optional    |
+----+-------------+
```

I'm done of for first nested for game type relation but i dont know how to add another group by for game categories

```
$game_providers = GameProvider::all();

$game_providers = $game_providers->groupBy(function ($game_provider) {
    return $game_provider->game_type->name;
})->all();
```

and its output

```
Array{
 'Chess' => Array{
    0 => Array{
     'id'               => 1,
     'game_name'        => 'Sample',
     'game_type_id'     => 1,
     'game_category_id' => 2
    },
    1 => Array{
     'id'               => 2,
     'game_name'        => 'Sample 0',
     'game_type_id'     => 1,
     'game_category_id' => 2
    },
  },
 'Poker' => Array{
    0 => Array{
     'id'               => 3,
     'game_name'        => 'Sample 1',
     'game_type_id'     => 2,
     'game_category_id' => 1
    },
    1 => Array{
     'id'               => 4,
     'game_name'        => 'Sample 2',
     'game_type_id'     => 2,
     'game_category_id' => 2
    },
  },
}
```

**My expected output**

```
Array{
 'Chess' => Array{
    'Recommended' => Array{
        0 => Array{
           'id'               => 1,
            'game_name'        => 'Sample',
            'game_type_id'     => 1,
            'game_category_id' => 2
        }
    },
    'Optional' => Array{
        0 => Array{
            'id'               => 2,
            'game_name'        => 'Sample 0',
            'game_type_id'     => 1,
            'game_category_id' => 2
        }
    }
  },
 'Poker' => Array{
    'Recommended' => Array{
        0 => Array{
            'id'               => 3,
            'game_name'        => 'Sample 1',
            'game_type_id'     => 2,
            'game_category_id' => 1
        }
    },
    'Optional' => Array{
        0 => Array{
            'id'               => 4,
            'game_name'        => 'Sample 2',
            'game_type_id'     => 2,
            'game_category_id' => 2
        }
    }     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With L5, one way of acieving this can be:

```
GameProvider::with('game_categories.game_types')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy([
        'gameTypes.name',
        'gameCategories.name'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something along the lines of :

```
GameProvider::with('game_categories.game_types')->get()->map(function ($game) {
    return $game->game_categories->groupBy('name')->map(function ($catGame) {
        return $catGame->map(function ($category) {
            return $category->game_types->groupBy('name');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @FransEricDelaCruz what is not working ? Apperently you need to tweak based on your code but that is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Because Laravel use `EXISTS` method whether the item has relationship or not and also will use another query to load relations so query cant group data by column that is not loaded.

you can use manually join instead of `with()` method and then group data by nested column:

```
$user = App\Models\GameProvider::all()
        ->join('game_types', 'game_types.id', '=', 'games.game_type_id')
        ->groupBy('game_types.id')
        ->get();
```